# How do I make the Slider Control's slider wider? (using MFC)

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

[image: Current look of the slider]

[image: What I want the slider to look like]

I'm wondering how would I adjust the slider to make the width wider then it is?

First image is an image of the current state.
The second image is an image of what I'm looking for..
The slider is a CSlierCtrl and I'm using mfc.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [CSliderCtrl::SetThumbLength()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386822.aspx).